# Selenium not finding element that is there after switching windows

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to log in to medium.com for solely experimental purposes using selenium so that I have access to premium articles. I am able to click sign in with email on the login page however I can not seem to get selenium to locate the text box that appears afterward. It is my understanding that this text box appears in another window on the same page so I switched the driver to the second window that appears in the driver handler after clicking sign in with the email and still nothing.

```
import requests as re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pymongo
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = Options()
options.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "C:\\Users\Dominick\Desktop\chromedriver.exe", options = options)

driver.get('https://medium.com/m/signin')

driver.find_element_by_id("email-susi-button-text").click()

window = driver.window_handles[1].replace('CDwindow-', '')

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

try:
    #inputdiv = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//aria-label[1]')
    #inputdiv = driver.find_element_by_class_name('bs b bt bu dj')
    #inputdiv = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('input')
    #inputdiv = driver.find_element_by_class_name('eo al')
    inputdiv = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'eo al')))

    print('Success')
except NoSuchElementException:
    print('Element not found')
```

All the commented-out codes in the try/except statement are different methods I used to find the matching HTML for the text box. When I set brake points and observe the driver. page source the HTML that's revealed contains everything I am looking for however I can not seem to locate it properly with selenium.

Here is the raw HTML that I copy from driver.pagesource in interactive mode or with breakpoints

```
<iframe src="https://a16180790160.cdn.optimizely.com/client_storage/a16180790160.html" hidden="" tabindex="-1" title="Optimizely Internal Frame" height="0" width="0" style="display: none;"></iframe><div><div role="dialog" aria-modal="true" class="l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z" tabindex="-1"><div class="ab ac ae af ag ah"><div class="ai aj ak al am an ao ap aq ar as"><div class="at" id="susi-modal-background"><div class="ai au av aw l ax ay az ba bb bc"><div class="bd be l m bf n bg bh bi bj bb"><div class="at" id="susi-modal-header"><h2 class="bk b bl bm bn bo bp">Sign in with email</h2></div><div class="at" id="susi-modal-subheader"><div class="bq br al g"><h4 class="bs b bt bu bv">Enter the email address associated with your account, and we’ll send a magic link to your inbox.</h4></div></div><div class="bw al"><div class="l m bf"><div class="du by al"><div class=""><div class="el eg l m bf bh"><div class="bx al em en"><p class="bs b di cb bv"><div class="">Your email</div></p></div><div class="am"><div class="eo al"><p class="bs b bt bu dj"><input aria-label="email" aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="error" class="dv dw dx dy dz ea eb ec ed ee ef eg eh ei ej bh bv ek" pattern=".*" type="text" value=""></p></div></div></div></div></div><div class="ep by al"><button class="bs b ca cb eq cc er es et eu ev ch ew ex ey ez ci fa ck cl cm cn co">Continue</button></div><div class="fb du by al"><p class="bs b ca cb dj"><button class="cs ct cu cv cw cx cy cz da ch db dc dd de df"><svg class="dr ds dt" width="19" height="19" viewBox="0 0 19 19"><path d="M11.47 13.97L6.99 9.48 11.47 5l.55.5-3.99 3.98 4 4z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>All sign in options</button></p></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></body></html>
```

I will say however when I do print(driver.pagesource) the HTML that gets printed does not contain the same HTML that is revealed when observing the live variable driver.pagesource for wtv reasons. When I print() the page source the HTML seems to be indicative of the first window. I'm not sure what's going on as revealing the variables in live mode shows that the driver.pagesource contains the HTML I am looking for at the proper time to be located. I even tried using WebDriverWait as shown above to make sure the element I was looking for loaded in time, however that just ends up timing out as it doesn't find the element.

Answer (score 0):

We need to Switch to new window when we are trying to find element in a newly opened browser window.

When clicked on the `Sign in with email` option, the textbox element appears in the same window.

Try like below and confirm:

```
driver.get("https://medium.com/m/signin")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"email-susi-button-clickable"))).click()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@aria-label='email']"))).send_keys("sample@gmail.com")
```

Comment: I tried the above code, it just times out while waiting for the element to appear. I think that the website does in fact open a new window but it's displayed as just one window if that would be correct. After clicking the email button a new window get's added to the window handler of selenium which displays that text box. I gave the above code a shot though and still a timeout.

Comment: @Fijistreams - The code runs without any error for me.